# What are heap sizes and how can I check the current settings?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, jvm, heap-memory

I've never before came across the term "[heap size](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka/deployment.html#memory)" before. I've done some reading and I came to conclusion that command `export KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS="-Xmx16G -Xms16G"` would result in 16GB heap size.

I know that default size should be 512MB, but how can I check settings on the running Kafka server? Is checking the config file the only way to find out what are the current settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> default size should be 512MB

In Kafka, it's actually 1G, by default.

You can look at the running processes on the machine, such as `ps aux | grep KafkaServer` on Unix, and look at the `Xmx` for max heap...

For finding **current** heap usage (over time), you'll need to hook up JVM monitoring tools like Prometheus JMX exporter.

Comment: Thanks! I've used https://amalgjose.com/2020/03/02/how-to-set-kafka-heap-size/ as a reference for 512MB.

Comment: Well, that's wrong. Look at the source code https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/bin/kafka-server-start.sh#L29

Comment: I see it. Thanks one more time!